# If I uninstall a game does it delete my saves?

Tags: xbox-one

I'm thinking of uninstalling RYSE from my XB1 as I havent played it in a while and I want to free some disk space, but I am worried that if I do so that I will lose my game saves.

Does the XB1 delete the saves or does it keep them / store them in the cloud?

Comment: From what I know, the PS Vita is the only console to delete game data and save games together. It's its most annoying features in my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Xbox One reserves some space to store save data. Therefore, even if you delete your game, your save data should be intact. Secondly, your sava data should automatically be backed up in the cloud, regardless if you have Xbox Live.

---

## Sources:

[Understand and manage storage on Xbox One](http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-one/system/manage-storage?icid=furl_xboxone-storage)
[Manage game saves in the cloud on Xbox One](http://support.xbox.com/en-AU/xbox-one/games/manage-cloud-saves)